# Angular : Unable to load data and change view successfully

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, view

I have a page that contains an ng-view.  This embedded template is a table that, when a row is clicked on switches to the detail template for that row.  I have been unable to get the controller to gather the 'detail' data and successfully display it.

With the code below, the data is collected via $http.get, and the 'detail' view is shown, however the data is not bound to the 'detail' view.

Can someone please explain where I am going wrong here?

**Controller.js**

```
(function(){
    var appName = 'theApp'
    var app = angular.module('theApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function appConfig($locationProvider, $routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        //route that is called when "Show Location" is called below.
        .when( '/' + appName + '/location/:id', {
            controller: 'Controller',
            templateUrl: function(params){ return appName + '/location/detail/'+params.id; }
        })
        .when('/' + appName + '/location',{
            controller: 'Controller',
            templateUrl: function(params){return appName + '/location/list'}
        })

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });

    app.controller('Controller', function($scope, $location, $window, $http){
        $http.get('/Service/data/location/list').success(function(locationData) {

            $scope.locationList = locationList;
            $scope.locationDetail = locationDetail;
        });

        $scope.showLocation = function(id){
            $http.get('/Service/data/locations/detail/'+id)
                .success( function(locationDetail){
                    //data exists here
                    $scope.locationDetail = locationDetail;
                    //data successfully updated to $scope at this point.
                    $location.url($location.path() + '/' + id);
                    //templateUrl successfully shown, but without data.
            });
        };  
    } )   
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Angular data does not persist across views. Once a view goes away, all the data on the view's $scope also gets wiped out. What you need to do is save the data in a Factory.

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795815/angular-service-to-pass-data-to-another-controlelr/34796277#34796277), it explains about how to pass data from 1 view to another.

```js
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .factory('myFactory', myFactory)
    .controller('myCtrl1', myCtrl1)
    .controller('myCtrl2', myCtrl2);

  function myFactory() {
    var fromSender = null;
    return {
      setSender: function(sender) {
        fromSender = sender;
      },
      getSender: function() {
        return fromSender;
      }
    };
  }

  function myCtrl1(myFactory) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.setSender = myFactory.setSender;
  }

  function myCtrl2(myFactory) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.getSender = myFactory.getSender;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl1 as ctrl1">
    Controller 1: <br>
    <button ng-click="ctrl1.setSender('from controller 1')">Send to myFactory</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl2 as ctrl2">
    Controller 2: <br>
    value from ctrl1 via myFactory:  {{ctrl2.getSender()}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.